# Callbacks in C++

Tags: c++, callback

I am working on a project where I need callbacks as they make our work easier and help us write cleaner code. But I wasn't able to find any.

Are there any callbacks in C++ like the delegates in C#?
If yes, how to use them?
If no, is there any other option?

Comment: lambdas and `std::function` is what I would use if I need to store the callbacks.

Comment: A 'callback' is a paradigm, an idea that you can write code as a function, pass that function to some other part of the program and expect it to be called at a certain time/event. In C# there is the notion of writing delegates and the VM supporting that, in C++ you can pass the address of the function (see function pointers), or use the wrappers like std::function or functor objects.

Comment: I suggest you not to use std::function if you care about performance

Comment: @Hrisip I can imagine why you say that, but please do not spread such handwavy recommendation without the "why". This will just lead to cargo cult. The tiny overhead is due to type erasure and some form of runtime polymorphism. Hence it is pointless to avoid `std::function` in favour of eg runtime polymorphism

Comment: You can try something like https://marcmo.github.io/delegates/ .

Comment: @idclev463035818, std::function allocates memory. And I see you're not very familiar with the needs of those who need a callback/delegate.

Comment: @Hrisip "I see you're not very familiar with the needs of those who need a callback/delegate" I don't understand how you see that. Such statement just shows me that I don't want to discuss any further

Comment: If your issue has been solved, please mark the answer as accepted. If that is not the answer which solved your issue (it should have though; it's pretty detailed) please post an answer to the question explaining how you solved the problem. Marking the question as "solved" and editing the question to include the answer is not acceptable. Question part should hold only the question

Comment: I posted the answer about 3-4 times but someone votes to delete the answer and it gets deleted. I even tried to edit the question, but again someone edited it to remove the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and your help, now I have got a `delegate system` running in `C++` almost like the one we see in `C#`. Here's the full code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Delegate
{
    private:
        typedef T (*Function) (Args... args);
        std::vector <Function> functions;

    public :
        Delegate ()
        {
            functions = std::vector <Function> ();
        }

        ~Delegate ()
        {
            functions.clear ();
        }

        const void Invoke (const Args&&... args) const
        {
            for (Function func : functions)
            {
                func (args...);
            }
        }

        void Invoke (Args&&... args)
        {
            for (Function func : functions)
            {
                func (args...);
            }
        }

        const void operator () (const Args&&... args) const
        {
            for (Function func : functions)
            {
                func (args...);
            }
        }

        void operator () (Args&&... args)
        {
            for (Function func : functions)
            {
                func (args...);
            }
        }

        const void operator += (const Function func) const
        {
            functions.push_back (func);
        }

        void operator += (Function func)
        {
            functions.push_back (func);
        }

        const void AddListener (const Function func) const
        {
            functions.push_back (func);
        }

        void AddListener (Function func)
        {
            functions.push_back (func);
        }
};

void Log1 (const char* msg)
{
    std :: cout << msg << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << "Called by Log 1" << std :: endl;
}

void Log2 (const char* msg)
{
    std :: cout << msg << std :: endl;
    std :: cout << "Called by Log 2" << std :: endl;
}

int main ()
{
    Delegate <void, const char*> del;
    del += Log1;
    del += Log2;
    del ("Hello World!");
    std :: cin.get ();
}
```

The first `typename` in the `template` is gonna be the `return type` and the others (unlimited) are gonna be the `parameters` which are optional.

Anyone can use this code freely anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C# and I don't know delegates. Hence, I add what I will use as basis to answer your question here (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)):

> A delegate is a type that represents references to methods with a
> particular parameter list and return type. When you instantiate a
> delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a
> compatible signature and return type. You can invoke (or call) the
> method through the delegate instance.

---

I believe C++ has no direct replacement for C# delegates, but it has [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). You can store almost any callable in `std::function` to invoke it later. The most convenient way to define a callable on the fly is a lambda expression:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    std::vector< std::function< void()>> callbacks;
    void call_all() {
        for (auto& f : callbacks){
            f();
        }
    }
};

void bar() {
    std::cout << "I am a callback\n";
}

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.callbacks.push_back(bar);
    f.callbacks.push_back( [](){ std::cout << "I am another callback"; });
    f.call_all();
}
```

I used the most simple case of no arguments and no return type. For example `std::function<int(const Foo&)>` can store callables that have a `const Foo&` argument and return `int`. Storing callables with different signatures in the same container is more complicated.